# Changing the labels in multiple ggplot legends

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the diamonds data set and the following code I created the fig below.

```
ggplot(diamonds[diamonds$color == c("D", "E", "F"),], aes(x=carat, y=price, shape = color, color=cut)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

I am trying to change the legend labels (not titles) to something other than they currently are.

I have been trying the code (below) for a single legend

```
ggplot(diamonds[diamonds$color == c("D", "E", "F"),], aes(x=carat, y=price, shape = color, color=cut)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_shape_manual(lables = c("DDD", "EEE", "FFF"))
```

But get this error:

```
Error in discrete_scale(aesthetic, "manual", pal, ...) : 
  unused argument (lables = c("DDD", "EEE", "FFF"))
```

How do you specify the legend to be altered when there are two?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can use factor to change label of each level

```
diamonds2 <- diamonds[diamonds$color == c("D", "E", "F"),]
diamonds2$color <- factor(diamonds2$color, levels = c('D', 'E', 'F'), labels = c("DDD", "EEE", "FFF"))

ggplot(diamonds2, aes(x=carat, y=price, shape = color, color=cut)) +
  geom_point()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you pass `values` as well to `scale_shape_manual` you can change the legend labels.

```
ggplot(diamonds[diamonds$color == c("D", "E", "F"),], aes(x=carat, y=price, shape = color, color=cut)) +  geom_point() + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=1:3,
                      labels=c("CCC", "DDD", "EEE"))
```

Produces:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Note your typo *lables* instead *labels* that's causing the error. Try

```
scale_shape_discrete(labels = c("DDD", "EEE", "FFF"))
```